# How to accept Huge amount of API requests in Node JS

Tags: javascript, java, node.js

I recently started learning Node JS. And things went pretty well. I saw an online tutorial and accepted GET request in my server.js file.

Since I'm from a Java background, a few questions arrived into my mind and I searched them all over the Internet but could not find them out.

1. Do I need to accept all my requests within request.js file. Suppose if I have hundreds of GET api requests do I need to write them in my server.js file which I feel is the only entry point in Node JS.

For Example:

```
var express=require("express");
var app=express();
app.get("/api/request1/",function(){
    //some code here
})
app.get("/api/request2/",function(){
    //some code here
})
.
.  
.
.
app.get("/api/request100/",function(){
    //some code here
})
```

This would make my code cumbersome and difficult to manage. As I said I have a Java background and I used to separate my code in different Servlets.

2. Secondly is it possible to have another entry point in Node JS. Since my application is quite big. Also is there a way to use Node Modules to segregate/separate my code within different modules and then include them in server.js.

Please specify some good resource or a technique how to overcome this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily modularize your express routes.

To follow your example: in your project, create a directory `routes` and a file `routes/api.js` with the following contents:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/request1', function(req, res, next) {
  res.send('...');
});
router.get('/request2', function(req, res, next) {
  res.send('...');
});

module.exports = router;
```

And in your `server.js`:

```
app.use('/api', require('./routes/api'));
```

Just in case someone has the same question you can refer to the [Express routing documentation](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html)

Comment: Thanks almost the answer I was looking for. May be I should have gone from Express Documentation.Thanks. Can I export multiple routes. For example I have separated my routes in routes/api.js ,  routes/moreapi.js ,  routes/onr-moreapi.js

Comment: Thanks a lot Robby you saved my tons of hours.

Answer (score 1):

`app.get(...)` is just a function call. You can easily do this:

```
require('routes1')(app);
require('routes2')(app);
```

where those modules export `function(app) { app.get(...); app.get(...); }`

Even better, Express.js (not Node.js - Node.js is like JVM, Express is like Tomcat) apps can mount subapps:

```
app.use('/api', require('subapp'));
```

If `subapp` is a normal Express.app with, say, `app.get('/request1', ...)`, then, after mounting, you will have `/api/request1` available to you. (This only works for entire hierarchies; so if you want to split your `/api/request1`...`/api/request100` into ten files, you might want to use the first approach, or rethink how your hierarchy works.)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you should maintain separation as much as possible with your modules, as i see you have started learning express do checkout [express-generator](http://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html) module that provides you with a nice small boiler-plate code to start from as well when structuring a large project also check out blog [best-practices-express-structure](https://www.terlici.com/2014/08/25/best-practices-express-structure.html) for advanced usage

Comment: Sure, Thanks for the links